# Gauss Lucas, convex hull, question about why the coefficients sum to 1

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: page1]

In looking at the above proof of the Gauss-Lucas theorem, proving that the roots of P′ all lie within the convex hull of the roots of P I have a question about why z is a weighted sum with positive coefficients that sum to one. I can see the rhs is of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{|z-a_i|^2}a_i$. It can be considered a weighted sum, but how does it equal 1?

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient in front of $a_i$ is
$$\frac{1}{|z-a_i|^2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{|z-a_k|^2}\right)^{-1}$$
Their sum is clearly $1$.

Comment: I am not seeing why @Tuvasbien. The part in brackets is a sum and its not 1. Can you please help

Comment: The sum in the bracket is not $1$. Let $\displaystyle S=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{|z-a_k|^2}$, then the coefficient in front of $a_i$ is $\frac{1}{S|z-a_i|^2}$ but $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{S|z-a_i|^2}=\frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{|z-a_i|^2}=\frac{S}{S}=1$$

Comment: Thanks @Tuvasbien

Comment: how does this prove the last statement that $z=1. a_i +  \sum_{j=1 i \neq j}^n a_j .0$? What we have is that $z=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$. @Tuvasbien

Comment: If $P(z)\neq 0$, we showed that $z=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i a_i$ where $\alpha_i\geqslant 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=1$. If $P(z)=0$ then $z$ is one of the $a_i$ and of course $z=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i a_i$ for some $\alpha_i\geqslant 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=1$, if $z=a_i$ we can take $\alpha_i=1$ and $\alpha_j=0$ for $j\neq i$.